# how to summarize numeric and factor level values simultaneously in R

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, summarize

I'm trying to summarize a dataset by grouping on one column (F1) and getting the average of the other columns, except that the other columns are split between numeric and factor levels. I can use ddply to summarize F2 numeric values but not sure how to do the same for the factor levels in F3. I tried to capture the mos repeated factor level by group but this is not working.

**reproducible example**

```
library(plyr)
set.seed(37)
df<-data.frame("F1"=rep(LETTERS[1:5],each = 3),
               "F2"= 1:15,
               "F3"= sample(c("Yes","No"), 15, replace=TRUE))
df2 <- ddply(df,~F1,summarise,
                     mF2=mean(F2),
                     mF3=tail(names(sort(table(df$F3))), 1))
> df
   F1 F2  F3
1   A  1  No
2   A  2 Yes
3   A  3  No
4   B  4 Yes
5   B  5  No
6   B  6  No
7   C  7 Yes
8   C  8 Yes
9   C  9 Yes
10  D 10 Yes
11  D 11 Yes
12  D 12  No
13  E 13 Yes
14  E 14 Yes
15  E 15  No
> df2
  F1 mF2 mF3
1  A   2 Yes
2  B   5 Yes
3  C   8 Yes
4  D  11 Yes
5  E  14 Yes
```

Instead, df2 should look like this:

```
> df2
  F1 mF2 mF3
1  A   2 No
2  B   5 No
3  C   8 Yes
4  D  11 Yes
5  E  14 Yes
```

I'd be keen to try with dplyr or other method if shown how.

Comment: Why are you using `table(df$F3)` instead f just `table(F3)`? This way you are doing it for the whole data set instead of the subset. You could easily convert your plyr code to dplyr too by doing something like `df %>% group_by(F1) %>% summarise(mF2 = mean(F2), mF3 = tail(names(sort(table(F3))), 1))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can use similar option in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(F1) %>% 
  summarise(mF2 = mean(F2), mF3 = tail(names(sort(table(F3))),1))
```

Comment: That is not addressing the "unexpected" behavior OP had

Comment: @DavidArenburg  I was looking at the `I'd keep to try it in dplyr`

Comment: @akrun: spits out 1 row. whats missing for it to match the ddply output above?

Comment: @val use `dplyr::summarise(mF2 = mean(..`

Comment: @val it has nothing to do with new ways. If you don't understand what you are doing wrong, how a code dump will help you understand it better?

Comment: @DavidArenburg: indeed, the landscape usually is easier to see from the mountaintops.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I saw your comment about why it happened, so I didn't specify it in my solution.  ONce I posted the solution, I found that you updated with a dplyr solution